# Does anybody know software for customising audio themes?

Tags: software-recommendation, sound, themes

I am interested in simple managing of audio themes in Ubuntu (10.10). Does anybody know a software for customising/managing/changing Ubuntu audio themes?

Thanks for every suggestion.
Regards,
Vincenzo

Comment: What's wrong with the built in built in,**system>>preferences>>sound**??

Comment: I would like to customise sound themes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Sound Theme Manager](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Edavid4dev/sound-theme-manager/rewrite)

[image: bzr branch]

Sound Theme Manager is a program for managing [freedesktop.org sound themes](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/sound-theme-spec) that can:

- Set the desktop sound theme.
- Create sound theme packages from existing themes.
- Install sound theme packages.
- Remove sound themes.
- Play a preview sound for a sound theme.
- Browse through the sounds in a theme and play them.
- Create new sound themes.
- Edit sound theme metadata.
- Edit the sound theme sounds.

It currently only supports a (large) subset of the sound theme specification but will eventually be fully compliant.

---

**Full Disclosure:** I am the developer.

Comment: Thanks !!! I'll try to use it and, maybe 'dig in to the python API' :)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no software for customizing these themes, but doing so is simple. If you take a look at the current themes, you will notice that they are defined by a text file.

You can find the specification [here](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/sound-theme-spec), and you can use [audacity](http://packages.ubuntu.com/audacity) for editing the audio.